# How to calculate max sum held over a month?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, spreadsheet, google-spreadsheets

I need help with a formula that needs to calculate the max sum held at one time for each month.
In this example it would be 54 for March (12+13+14+15, held on the 29/03/2021). Month is determined by "Held from".

| Sum | Held from | To |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 01/03/2021 | 10/03/2021 |
| 11 | 05/03/2021 | 15/03/2021 |
| 12 | 14/03/2021 | still holding |
| 13 | 28/03/2021 | 10/04/2021 |
| 14 | 29/03/2021 | 29/03/2021 |
| 15 | 29/03/2021 | 29/03/2021 |
| 15 | 01/04/2021 | still holding |

Comment: Seems it getting SUM between two dates,,  since `54` calculates values between `14/03/2021` and  `29/03/2021` , you may use either SUMIFS or SUMPRODUCT !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your data looked like this:

[image]

I would create a separate sheet for held amount for every date:

[image]

`B2` would have this formula:

```
=SUMIFS(Sheet1!A:A,Sheet1!B:B,"<="&Sheet2!A2,Sheet1!C:C,">="&Sheet2!A2)
```

If your data has the text "still holding":

[image]

I would still create a separate sheet, but with longer formula in `B2`

```
=SUMIFS(Sheet1!A:A,Sheet1!B:B,"<="&Sheet2!A2,Sheet1!C:C,">="&Sheet2!A2)+SUMIFS(Sheet1!A:A,Sheet1!B:B,"<="&Sheet2!A2,Sheet1!C:C,"="&"still holding")
```

Then you could return max held amount by using something like this:

```
=MAXIFS(B:B,A:A,">="&DATE(E2,F2,1),A:A,"<="&EOMONTH(DATE(E2,F2,1),0))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, I was trying with SUMIF but your solution with SUMIFS is perfect.